# creating and saving a pdf in reportlab returns an error

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm trying to create a pdf using reportlab but I keep getting an error, ideally I want to save the created pdf to a specific directory but this is just for testing and the save function only saves it to the current working directory.

```
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4

folder_path = "/home/ro/A Python Scripts/dest_test/"
folder_name = os.path.basename(folder_path)
pdf_name = folder_name + '.py'

def generate_pdf(folder_paths, folder_names, speedy_share_links):
    c = canvas.Canvas(folder_names)

    c.drawString(100,780,folder_names)
    c.drawString(100,750,speedy_share_links)
    c.save()

generate_pdf(folder_path, folder_name, "hiya")
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf.py", line 16, in <module>
    generate_pdf(folder_path, folder_name, "hiya")
  File "pdf.py", line 14, in generate_pdf
    c.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfgen/canvas.py", line 1209, in save
    self._doc.SaveToFile(self._filename, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py", line 216, in SaveToFile
    f = open(filename, "wb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u''
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path has an empty basename, which is why the error shows the empty string.

Replace the line:

```
folder_path = "/home/ro/A Python Scripts/dest_test/"
```

With the line:

```
folder_path = "/home/ro/A Python Scripts/dest_test/foobar.pdf"
```

and your program will generate `foobar.pdf` in the current directory.